# How to make multiprocessing with "spawn" work in ipython or databricks notebooks

Tags: python, databricks, python-multiprocessing

I have to run some code in databricks notebooks. Since things are very slow I added multiprocessing with great success regarding speed. However, in many runs i had kind of deadlock situation. No more progress and not new logs ...nothing. Just stuck while the CPU seems to be doing nothing. After lots of digging and reading i am pretty sure its because of using "fork" start method that these deadlocks occur from. Thus I would like to try "spawn" instead. However, that seems not work properly with IPython/Databricks.
It always stuck when using multiprocessing library but i heard it should work with multiprocess library because it does employ dill for pickling.
Yet now my issues is that the function is not available.
The error is: NameError: name 'my_other_function' is not defined

I read to solve this I have to put things in separate module so it is reimpoted during spawn.
Is there any other solution to this while keeping everything in one Databricks notebook?

This is a very simplified version which should show the problem.

```
import multiprocess

def my_other_function(i: int):
    return i*i

def my_function(i: int):

    res = my_other_function(i)
    print(f"result:{res}")
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with multiprocess.get_context("spawn").Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        numbers = list(range(10))
        results = pool.map(my_function, numbers)
        print(f"results:{results}")e here
```